# Android button stuck in a particular state

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, user-interface, android-activity

I have a issue with my button.Button is supposed to call any one of two methods depending on the conditions.The problem I am facing is that when the method turnOnFlash() is called once, the program remains in it's state and the button simply stops responding.Is there some way I can make this work

the code for button is

```
btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnOnFlash();  

            }
        }
    });
```

and the code for the method turnOnFlash is

```
public void turnOnFlash() {


    isFlashOn = true;
    // ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo();
    // T1.setPriority(10);
    // start new thread to flash
    // T1.start();
    // T1.run();
    toggleButtonImage();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


    // changing button/switch image
    //toggleButtonImage();
    //ImageButton btnSwitch1;

    Visualizer mVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
    int capRate = Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate();
    int capSize = Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1];
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(capSize);
    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {




            Camera cam = Camera.open();
            Parameters params;
            int length = bytes.length;
            params = cam.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                Log.w("Morphyre", "Found Nonzero sample " + bytes[i]);
                if (bytes[i] > 90 || bytes[i] <= -90) {
                    Log.d("hehe", "pepe");
                    params = cam.getParameters();
                    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    cam.setParameters(params);
                    cam.stopPreview();

                } else {

                    params = cam.getParameters();
                    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    cam.setParameters(params);
                    cam.startPreview();
                    //Log.d("check", "control");
                }

            }
            if (cam != null) {
                cam.stopPreview();
                cam.release();
                cam = null;
            }
            bytes = null;
            System.gc();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate) {
        }

    };

    int status = mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
            capRate, true/* wave */, false/* no fft needed */);
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);  }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the button stops responding? Does your entire app freeze?

Comment: I can still run the app in the background, i.e. minimize the app and open up something else, but my button never responds .

Comment: Are you remembering to toggle your `isFlashOn` variable from `false` to `true` and vise versa?

Comment: Yes I do that , I think the problem lies with the data capture part because if I comment out that part , both methods get called accordingly with the button clicks.

Comment: Perhaps for debugging, you should disable your `turnOnFlash` and `turnOffFlash` method and instead just do a simple `Toast` when you think it should be on or off. I think the problem is not within your `Button` but something to do with how you are trying to control the flashlight.

Comment: The main problem I think is that onWaveFormDataCapture never stops capturing data but I just can't think of a way to stop it.

Comment: I apologize but I personally have never worked with the flash light before so I'm not sure how much more help I can give you at least as far as what your original posted question is then.